# How to increase the tps(transaction per second) in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have to achieve tps of around 2000 in jmeter but able to get around 1000 tried following things -

-Increasing the config
-Distributed Load Testing
-Increasing heap memory
-Increasing or keeping the threads as per the standard formula(followed jmeter best practices)

is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally in order to get more throughput you need to [add more threads](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users) (virtual users) in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

If you cannot add more threads due to lack of resources (CPU, RAM, etc.) - consider switching to [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Of course the system under test must be able to respond fast enough because if the application you're testing isn't capable of serving more than 1000 requests per second - you won't be able to get more unless you identify and fix the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing)

Comment: Hi Dimitri Thanks... but while adding more threads Avg is increasing which resulting in decrease of TPS.
When we are increasing the resources vertically we are able to increase the tps but not with the horizontal scaling